# call Function in Form1 from Form2 in c#

Tags: .net, winforms, c#-4.0

i have the following function in Form1 and would like to call it when a button in Form2 is clicked.

```
   public object GetStudents()
    {
        using (var DB = new myView1())
        {
            var studentList = (from s in DB.View123
                            select new { s.StudentName, s.StudentNumber, s.ClassName, s.StreamName, s.ParentName }).ToList();
            dataGridViewStudents.DataSource = students;
            return students.ToList();
        }
    }
```

Above function is in Form1, how do i call it from a button_Click event in Form2. This is some thing simple in VB.NET

Comment: do you have a variable of type `Form1` somewhere? It's about the same in C# and VB.Net.

Comment: This is a gem! Combined with your question this is the best example for intermixing the presentation layer and that business logic I've seen in a long time. To give you a proper reply: Why don't you put the data retrieval code into its own class? In that case, both forms could use it without the cross-dependencies you're about to introduce.

Comment: @Thorsten Dittmar: but besides the gem side of it, how do u simply accomplish what i asked? ---- just assume this is for a quick demo and code will be refactored!!

Comment: @SQL.NET Warrior, if you have to ask this many questions about one application maybe think about attempting a more basic project.

Comment: Well, pass an instance of `Form1` to `Form2` or create an instance of `Form1` at the point where you need it. But why not refactor it right away...

Comment: @Ash Burlaczenko: Every one has been a leaner at sometime,  David's answer below is the guidance i needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's also simple in C#.  You just need an instance of `Form1` and then you can call this method on that instance.

However, there's a better approach.  This code doesn't actually *belong* on a form.  Forms are for UI interactions, not for business logic and data access.  You're better off moving this code to a common location which would be accessed by both forms.

Create a data access class.  Something like this:

```
public class StudentRepository
{
    public static object GetStudents()
    {
        using (var DB = new myView1())
        {
            var studentList = (from s in DB.View123
                        select new { s.StudentName, s.StudentNumber, s.ClassName, s.StreamName, s.ParentName }).ToList();
            dataGridViewStudents.DataSource = students;
            return students.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Notice also that the method is now `static` which means it doesn't need an instance to be called.  (This is like the `Shared` keyword in VB.)  So your forms can just call:

```
var students = StudentRepository.GetStudents();
```

Another thing you'll want to fix, although it's outside the scope of this question, is that return type.  `object` isn't very specific.  You should have a `Student` class and that method should return `IList<Student>`.  Something like this:

```
public class Student
{
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public int StudentNumber { get; set; }
    public string ClassName { get; set; }
    public string StreamName { get; set; }
    public string ParentName { get; set; }
}
```

and:

```
public class StudentRepository
{
    public static IList<Student> GetStudents()
    {
        using (var DB = new myView1())
        {
            var studentList = (from s in DB.View123
                        select new Student { StudentName = s.StudentName, StudentNumber = s.StudentNumber, ClassName = s.ClassName, StreamName = s.StreamName, ParentName = s.ParentName }).ToList();
            dataGridViewStudents.DataSource = students;
            return students.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

I made some assumptions about the types for the fields, you should be able to correct those if they're wrong.  You might even want it to return an `IEnumerable<Student>` instead of `IList<Student>` if it's an unchanging result (that is, if it's just an enumeration of students and not a list to be added to, removed from, etc.).

There's a lot more you can do here, such as having an object for other data elements such as `Class` (which might need a different name, just to be clean), `Parent`, `Stream`, etc.  (Come to think of it, several of these might need better names.  Your variable naming in general needs a little work.  Things like `Form1` or `myView1` don't convey intent very well.)

Answer (score 2):

You need to give your `Form2` instance a reference to a `Form1` instance, at which point it would be as simple as `form1.GetStudents()`.

If `Form1` is your main form you could simply do

```
var students = ((Form1)ApplicationContext.MainForm).GetStudents();
```

However, there are several parts of with this code that give off a bad code smell:

- Database code inside a `Form` (it's not the form's responsibility really)
- Method that returns `object` instead of an `IList`
- Not clear what `ApplicationContext.MainForm` is without context (corollary: don't do this)

IMHO you should take this opportunity to refactor your existing code and bring it in line with acceptable practices.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, will surely have to do that

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with C# But it should be similar to VB.Net since it is still on the same framework. Have you tried putting your functions in a seperate resource file and adding it to the project? It seems like the reason you are unable to call the function is due to a scope problem from them being in different forms. Resource files should take care of that, and it tends to make code much easier to maintain since it reduces clutter